# Rails - Importing GMAIL Contacts & then Syncing with GMAIL, Updating Inserting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rubygems, google-contacts-api

does anyone know of a good gem for using the Google Contacts API? Where you can sync, update, add records to a user's google contacts account? I've search and can't tell which is the winner.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you just want to import contacts from gMail you could use

https://github.com/cardmagic/contacts

Comment: Thanks but I want to do more than import. I want to stay synced, and even push records in the future.

Comment: I don't have any solution for that :)

Comment: This library is too old (2 years) I am trying to run it with ruby 1.9.3 and rails 3 and doesn't work. Do you know another library more modern? Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

The updated gmail contacts gem for Ruby 1.9.3 and Rails 3 can be found here:

https://github.com/febuiles/gmail-contacts/